# How do I remove relative prices between radio options in Gravity Forms?

Tags: javascript, gravity-forms-plugin

Here's an example of how my "Options" field (from "Pricing Fields") is set up:

[image]

Here's how it appears when selecting an option:

[image]

I would like to replace the relative pricing with simply the absolute price of the option.

From [Gravity Wiz](https://gravitywiz.com/how-can-i-hide-the-price-difference-displayed-for-gravity-forms-option-fields/) I found a way to make the price disappear altogether:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gform_format_option_label( fullLabel, fieldLabel, priceLabel, selectedPrice, price, formId, fieldId ) { 
        return fieldLabel;
}
</script>
```

But I've played around with the available arguments and they do weird things, like tacking on an extra field label every time you select another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there was no way to do this with the parameters given by `gform_format_option_label`, unless you could figure out a way to take `fieldId` and look up the field's name, which, I'm sure is possible and the right way to go, but I couldn't figure it out.

Why couldn't I just use `fieldLabel + ' $' + price`? Because if you do that, then on every click, you tack on another price, because `fieldLabel` recursively *includes* the price!

To work around that, I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gform_format_option_label( fullLabel, fieldLabel, priceLabel, selectedPrice, price, formId, fieldId ) {
        if( fieldLabel.indexOf('$') == -1 ) fieldLabel += ' <span class="ginput_price">$' + price + '</span';
        return fieldLabel;
    }
</script>
```

Very hacky, but it does the job. It just says, *"Only tack on the price if there's not already a `$` in `fieldLabel`."*